# MySQL multiple columns reference the same column

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a table that have 5 columns as [id,s1,s2,s3,n]
and s1,s2,s3 and n reference id column of a table called s

but MySQL is refusing to add foreign key constraints. I have tried to search but non of the solutions work. I tried setting indexes still doesn't work.
SQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `char` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `s1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `s2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `s3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `n` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

ALTER TABLE `landuse`.`char` 
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_Char_S1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`s1` )
  REFERENCES `landuse`.`s` (`id` )
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE,  
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_Char_S2`
  FOREIGN KEY (`s2` )
  REFERENCES `landuse`.`s` (`id` )
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_Char_S3`
  FOREIGN KEY (`s3` )
  REFERENCES `landuse`.`s` (`id` )
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_Char_N`
  FOREIGN KEY (`n` )
  REFERENCES `landuse`.`s` (`id` )
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

//when i execute the above statement the following error apears

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
   (`landuse`.`#sql-14ec_2`, CONSTRAINT `FK_Char_S2` FOREIGN KEY (`s2`) REFERENCES `s` 
   (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

[Link to MySQL dump of the current database](http://textuploader.com/o5zv)
How can i set the foreign keys?

Comment: please add the create Statement so we can see what you tried.

Comment: I added the statements that i tried to set foreign key with too

Comment: As Jens said please paste here the real query so we can help. Try to export the DB and paste here in your question please

Comment: i added a link to the dump file

Comment: @AmanuelNega I have tried the statements by my own. And I get no error?

Comment: even the Add foreign key statment? my mysql says error

Comment: @AmanuelNega can you add the message?

Comment: Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`landuse`.`#sql-14ec_2`, CONSTRAINT `FK_Char_S2` FOREIGN KEY (`s2`) REFERENCES `s` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: can you show the create statement of table `landuse`

Comment: land use is name of the database!

Comment: If both tables are in the same DB you can remove it.

Comment: @AmanuelNega Can you please show the createstaement of s? Has `char`and `s` same engine (myisam) or (innodb) ? have thay all the type `int(11)`

Comment: yes.... all are the same! there is a link to the database dump!